# Find - replace - Update string using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, replace, awk, grep

I have a file containing a line like

```
https://abcdefgh.com/123/pqrst/456/xyz.html
```

So I want to search for this line in that file and replace the end part i.e. `xyz.html` with `mno.html`

Will take the `mno.html` as input in the shell script.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} index($0,"https://abcdefgh.com/123/pqrst/456/xyz.html"){$NF="mno.html"} 1' file
https://abcdefgh.com/123/pqrst/456/mno.html
```

or if both values are already stored in shell variables:

```
$ old="https://abcdefgh.com/123/pqrst/456/xyz.html"
$ new="mno.html"
$ awk -v old="$old" -v new="$new" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} index($0,old){$NF=new} 1' file
https://abcdefgh.com/123/pqrst/456/mno.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed '/https:\/\/abcdefgh.com\/123\/pqrst\/456\/xyz.html/s#\(.*\/\)\(.*\)#\1mno.html#g' yourfile
```

Comment: You should escape the `.` in `.com` and `.html`. It's also worth telling the OP they'd need to escape every other possible RE metacharacter, etc. that can occur in filenames too (e.g. `*`).

Answer (score 0):

using `awk` if the line is exactly as the example, I mean if there is no other characters before or after it

```
awk '{print gensub(/^(https:\/\/abcdefgh.com\/123\/pqrst\/456\/)xyz.html$/,"\\1mno.html","g")}' input.txt
```

Otherwise:

```
awk '{print gensub(/(https:\/\/abcdefgh.com\/123\/pqrst\/456\/)xyz.html/,"\\1mno.html","g")}' input.txt
```

Comment: You should mention this is GNU awk specific. You should escape the `.` in `.com` and `.html`. It's also worth telling the OP they'd need to escape every other possible RE metacharacter, etc. that can occur in filenames too (e.g. `*`). To be honest, though, I'd just use sed if I was going with an RE replacement approach and was OK with having to escape a bunch of characters.